# Implement multiple Consumable In-App Purchases

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Right first of all I have tried all kinds of tutorial but they only show how to get the purchase information and display it as a tableview then get the purchase to work, plus this is only for non-consumable or one consumable. As per the image above, I have created this in the XiB and would like to just initiate the consumable purchase when the user taps the button. I would not like to get the purchase info from iTunes Connect then display it as I am already displaying it offline.

I have created the App ID and the App in iTunes Connect and have created 5 in-app purchases. (as per the image below.) I would like the buttons to call for each of these. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: That's what I was talking about: Apple encourages you to use `[SKPayment paymentWithProduct:yourProduct]`. And, for that, you need to use SKProductsRequest :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experiense in working with consumable purchases, but I don't think there is a large difference. I hope, you've already read Apple In-App Purchasing Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH1-SW1

So, what is your problem? If you need to show multiple products in one viewController, you need to take somewhere a list with productIdentifiers (strings, unique for each product in you app at iTunes) for each product. You can hardcode these productIdentifiers, or, better, if you are using server, request them (because, if you hardcode your productIdentifiers, and then add/remove/edit product and it's productIdentifier changes, you'll need to publish a new patch for your app).

To show actual information about each product (price, name), you need to request it. You do it by creating SKProductRequest (for each product) and adding it to your paymentQueue. You'll get price in response. If you don't - don't even show that product in your viewController, because it's something wrong with that product.

To show the products offline you can implement some cache. May be it looks nice, but does it make sense to show "Buy" button if you are offline?

Probably there will be some kind of cell for each product in your viewController. In that case, that should be not a problem to determine, which productIdentifier to use, when user taps on some of the cells.

What to do after that? IMHO it's nicely described in Apple's guide.

If you need more help or some more specific questions - please, comment my post, or edit your question.

P.S. Be aware: in iOS 7 there are some number of changes in working with in-app purchases. Anyway, you can find all information at http://developer.apple.com/library/ .

**P.P.S.** Check this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380 . I hope you know, what I mean :) You can try to find some help at #iphonedev @ irc.freenode.net , for example. And search and search again. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You **need** to get product information via SKProductsRequest, because you need and SKPayment instance to make a purchase, and SKPayment can be created only with existing SKProduct, not just productIdentifier string.

You can use local cache to **show** prices to the user even when he is offline, **but** Apple forces you to get product info every time user tries to **purchase** something.

Taking product info is not a problem, anyway.

How to store a set/array of productIdentifiers? Read my previous answer.

Comment: So how did Bad Piggies do this? : http://mcdn2.angrybirdsnest.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Bad-Piggies-Super-Mechanic-Pig-Prices-310x232.jpg

Comment: You *can* show user price even like "100 thousands of hunderos of millions of dollars". But If you want to let him to make a purchase, you *will need* to get product info from AppStore. And he will see real price in the AppStore's popup, like "Do you want to purchase blablabla for X.XX $?"

Comment: Umm... I don't understand, but I think, Apple will reject your App, if you hardcode your price.

Comment: If sooner or later you'll need to request info about products, why don't you want to do it before showing the price? If you'll get some error, you still can to show locally saved price.